# Java arraylist - Check if the two items in arraylist index are set while generating random ints from list?

Tags: java, arraylist

My coordinates list:

```
    int[][] coords = {
       {3093, 3630 }, {3095, 3632}, {3098, 3633},
       {3101, 3633 }, {3104, 3631}, {3106, 3629}, 
       {3107, 3627}, {3108, 3624}, {3109, 3620},
       {3108, 3617}, {3106, 3614}, {3102, 3613},
       {3099, 3613}, {3097, 3613}, {3093, 3614},
       {3090, 3617}, {3087, 3619}
    };
```

Generation part:

```
    int random = Misc.random(coords.length - 1);
    handler.move(coords[random][0], coords[random][1], 0);
```

Basically what I am trying to do, if these coordinates are already taken, then re-generate the coords.

1. I can't really store these coords into a big arraylist, because I don't always want this feature to function, for example if I have more players than the items in the coords[] array, then this won't be activated.

Therefore I created a arraylist of used coords, and this is my logic on how to do this:

```
    int[][] coords = {
       {3093, 3630 }, {3095, 3632}, {3098, 3633},
       {3101, 3633 }, {3104, 3631}, {3106, 3629}, 
       {3107, 3627}, {3108, 3624}, {3109, 3620},
       {3108, 3617}, {3106, 3614}, {3102, 3613},
       {3099, 3613}, {3097, 3613}, {3093, 3614},
       {3090, 3617}, {3087, 3619}
    };

    ArrayList<Integer> coordinates = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int random = Misc.random(coords.length - 1);

    if (getPlayersCount() < coords.length) {
        if (coordinates.contains(coords[random][0], coords[random][1])) {
            random = Misc.random(coords.length - 1);
        }
        else {
            handler.move(coords[random][0], coords[random][1], 0);
            coords.add(coords[random][0], coords[random][1]);
        }
    }
    else {
        random = Misc.random(coords.length - 1);
        handler.move(coords[random][0], coords[random][1], 0);
    }
```

Basically, if there are less players than the array length, process.
If coordinates arraylist contains generated X, Y, regenerate it, else move player and add the coords to the list.

But it seems like I did something wrong, as I get this error: `error: no suitable method found for contains(int,int)`

***How can I do this?***

Comment: It would make your life easier to create a `class Coordinate { int lat; int long;}` and use it instead of `int[]`...

Comment: `contains` compares the `Object` you are passing with the `Object`s already in the list.  This is done by using the `Object`s `equals` method.  Your list contains arrays of `int`. While I'm sure there's some way to do it, I would be probably use something like `java.awt.Point` or make my own `Point` class and override it's `equals` method to compare the coordinates

Comment: @assylias You should extend that concept into an answer

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm feeling a bit lazy on that one: feel free to use the idea!

Comment: Assylias - I don't quite understand it, what lat and long supposed to be?

Comment: @JunatanmDegraded latitude and longitude. Or call it x and y... Just create a class to hold your coordinates instead of using arrays.

Comment: @assylias Dam, thought I was getting away with it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`ArrayList#contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) compares a `Object` with those objects contained within the list...

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one
>   element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

Your list contains arrays of `int`, which aren't easily comparable.

It would be much easier if you used a `Object` whose `equals` method was capable of comparing the coordinates of other similar objects.  Something like...

```
public class Coordinate {
    private int latitude;
    private int longitude;

    public Coordinate(int latitude, int longitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public int getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public int getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object value) {
        boolean equals = false;
        if (value instanceof Coordinate) {
            Coordinate coord = (Coordinate) value;
            equals = getLatitude() == coord.getLatitude() && getLongitude() == coord.getLongitude();
        }
        return equals;
    }

    //good practice to override hashcode when you override equals
    public int hashcode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 89 * hash + this.latitude;
        hash = 89 * hash + this.longitude;
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Then you could use something more like...

```
Coordinate[] coords = {
   new Coordinate(3093, 3630 ), new Coordinate(3095, 3632), new Coordinate(3098, 3633),
   new Coordinate(3101, 3633 ), new Coordinate(3104, 3631), new Coordinate(3106, 3629), 
   new Coordinate(3107, 3627), new Coordinate(3108, 3624), new Coordinate(3109, 3620),
   new Coordinate(3108, 3617), new Coordinate(3106, 3614), new Coordinate(3102, 3613),
   new Coordinate(3099, 3613), new Coordinate(3097, 3613), new Coordinate(3093, 3614),
   new Coordinate(3090, 3617), new Coordinate(3087, 3619)
};

ArrayList<Coordinate> coordinates = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();

int random = Misc.random(coords.length - 1);

if (getPlayersCount() < coords.length) {
    Coordinate coord = new Coordinate(coords[random].getLatitude(), coords[random].getLongitude());
    if (coordinates.contains(coord)) {
        random = Misc.random(coords.length - 1);
    }
    else {
        handler.move(coords[random].getLatitude(), coords[random].getLongitude(), 0);
        coordinates.add(coords[random]);
    }
}
else {
    random = Misc.random(coords.length - 1);
    handler.move(coords[random].getLatitude(), coords[random].getLongitude(), 0);
}
```

Comment: +1 very nice (except that long is not a valid name for your variable).

Comment: @assylias Nice catch, note pad didn't pick it up ;)

Comment: If have created a custom class for coordinates you could also use a `Set` instead of a `List` to avoid generating duplicates.

Comment: @assylias Thinks for the fixes, bloody ctrl+c is really messing up of late :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer I get this error: error: incompatible types
                   new Coordinate(3093, 3630), new Coordinate(3095, 3632), new Coordinate(3098, 3633),
                                               ^
  required: int
  found:    Coordinate

Comment: @JunatanmDegraded Yeah, I've updated the answer as well, didn't run it through an IDE first :P